# How to SPARQL optional

Tags: sparql

I have to use this Spaql query to retrive information about a person, my problem is to break the optional construct up into multiple optional constructs.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?abstract ?placeOfBirth 
    ?birthPlace ?birthDate ?page ?thumbnail 
WHERE { 
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> rdfs:label ?label ;
        dbo:abstract ?abstract ;
        foaf:page ?page .
    OPTIONAL {
        <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ;
            dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace ;
            dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
            dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
    }
    FILTER (LANG(?label) = 'en')    
    FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
}
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5):

### Splitting the OPTIONAL pattern into parts

The pattern

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ;
                                            dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace ;
                                            dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
                                            dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
```

is shorthand for four triple patterns:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
```

Instead of `OPTIONAL { …first pattern… }`, you just need to use four optional blocks, one for each of the four triple patterns:

```
optional { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth }
optional { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace }
optional { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbo:birthDate ?birthDate }
optional { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare> dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail }
```

### Other issues

It's worth nothing that language matching is a bit more complicated than string matching, so rather than

```
FILTER (LANG(?label) = 'en')    
FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
```

you should really be using

```
filter(langMatches(lang(?label),'en'))
filter(langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en'))
```

which allows you to retrieve results that use different language tags that are all English.

### `select distinct` and `limit 1` aren't both necessary

Notice that `select distinct` ensures that you don't have any duplicate rows in your results.  However, `limit 1` means that you'll only have one result at most anyhow, so there won't be any duplicates to remove.

### Standard Namespaces

It looks like you're querying against DBpedia, so it might be worthwhile to use the same namespace prefixes that the [public endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) defines, so that you can copy and paste queries and experiment more easily.  Doing that (and using a `values ?x { dbpedia:Ismail_Kadare }` to avoid some typing, we end up with this query:

```
select ?label ?abstract ?placeOfBirth ?birthPlace ?birthDate ?page ?thumbnail 
where { 
    values ?x { dbpedia:Ismail_Kadare }
    ?x rdfs:label ?label ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
       foaf:page ?page .
    optional { ?x dbpprop:placeOfBirth  ?placeOfBirth }
    optional { ?x dbpprop:birthPlace    ?birthPlace }
    optional { ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate }
    optional { ?x dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail }
    filter langMatches(lang(?label),'en')
    filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en')
}
limit 1
```

The DBpedia endpoint won't return anything for that query, but that's because http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ismail_Kadare doesn't have a `foaf:page` property, not because the query is malformed.  I don't know whether you're actually running this against DBpedia or not, so that may or not matter.

Comment: Could you suggest another person, for who DBpedia endpoint will return the result plz.

Comment: @balikatravella you can very easily find that out yourself, by modifying the above query: make the `foaf:page` property optional as well and look in the result which persons have a defined value for it.

Comment: @balikatravella There are lots of queries in questions here on StackOverflow in the [dbpedia and sparql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparql+dbpedia) tags that might help you.  I can't really help you out in modifying _this_ query, because _this_ query is trying to retrieve a value of the `foaf:page` property, and there isn't one.  You haven't given any other description of what data you're _trying_ to retrieve, so we can't very well fix the query since you haven't told us what it's _supposed_ to be doing.  (We can't fix if we don't know what's broken about it.)